# how to make jquery autocomplete ui using ajax in jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, jquery-ui

My problem is that jQuery UI AutoComplete is not working using AJAX in my JSP. I find many guides, but I cannot find the solution to my problem.

What I can do in this condition?

```
<%-- 
    Document   : Auto
    Created on : Feb 13, 2018, 4:24:31 PM
    Author     : Lenovo
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>


        <div class="ui-widget">
            <input type="text" id="auto"/>  
        </div>


        <script type="text/javascript">
           $(function()
           {
            $('#auto').autocomplete(
            {
            source:function(request,response)
            {
            //Fetch data
            $.ajax({
                url:"Fetch.jsp",
                method:"post",
                dataType:'json',
                data:{search:request.term},
                success:function(data)
                {
                    response(data.name);
                }
            });
            }
            });   
           }); 
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

This is my Fetch.jsp file:

```
<%@page import="org.json.JSONArray"%>
<%@page import="org.json.JSONObject"%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" language="java"%>
<%@page language="java" %>
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%
    try
    {
        String query = (String)request.getParameter("search");

        JSONObject json=new JSONObject();


        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sample","root","root");
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs;

        rs=st.executeQuery("select name from user2 where name like '"+query+"%'");
       while(rs.next())
       {
         json.put("name",rs.getString("name"));
         out.print(json.toString());   
       }

      }
      catch(Exception e1)
      {
      out.println(e1);
      }
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fetch.jsp should print a **json array**, not an object.
You are actually not printing a valid json, but json objects in sequence. You should print an array of the strings you got from the database.

Change:

```
JSONObject json=new JSONObject();
```

to

```
JSONArray json=new JSONArray();
```

and also change

```
while(rs.next())
{
     json.put("name",rs.getString("name"));
     out.print(json.toString());   
}
```

to

```
while(rs.next())
{
     json.put(rs.getString("name"));
}
out.print(json.toString());
```

And finally in your js:

```
success:function(data)
{
    response(data);
}
```

From the docs:

> A ***response*** callback, which expects a single argument: the data to suggest to the user. This data should be filtered based on the provided term... It's important, when providing a custom source callback, to handle errors during the request. You must always call the response callback even if you encounter an error. This ensures that the widget always has the correct state.

### References

- [Jquery UI Autocomplete API source: array, string or callback](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source)